# partial diff equation problem: canonical form

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

How do I bring the following equations to the canonical form? Please, I need all steps.

1. $\Bbb e ^{2y} \dfrac {\partial ^2 u} {\partial x^2} - 4x^2 \dfrac {\partial ^2 u} {\partial y^2} = 0$;
2. $x^2 \dfrac {\partial ^2 u} {\partial x^2} + y^2 \dfrac {\partial ^2 u} {\partial y^2} = 0$.

Comment: Please, be more precise in clarifying what kind of result you need and what passage of your attempt of solution has you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: [Canonical Forms or Normal Forms](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111103021/13.pdf)

Hints:

---

1. This is hyperbolic (Why?) so follow Example 1 in reference.

$$e^{2y}\alpha^2 -4x^2 = 0$$

$$\to \alpha^2 = \frac{4x^2}{e^{2y}}$$

$$\to \lambda_1 = \frac{2x}{e^{y}} \ \lambda_2 = \frac{-2x}{e^{y}}$$

$$\to \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\pm 2x}{e^{y}}$$

$$\to y = \ln(\pm x^2 + c)$$

$$\to y = \ln(x^2 + c_1), \ y = \ln(-x^2 + c_2)$$

Choose

$$\xi = c_1 = e^y - x^2$$

$$\eta = c_2 = e^y + x^2$$

Compute $\xi_x, \xi_y, \xi_{xx}, \xi_{yy}, \eta_x, \eta_y, \eta_{xx}, \eta_{yy}$ in:

[image]

Then plug back in $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$

---

2. This is elliptic (Why?) so follow Example 3 in reference.

$$x^2\alpha^2 + y^2 = 0$$

$$\to \alpha^2 = -\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

$$\to \lambda_1 = \frac{iy}{x} \ \lambda_2 = \frac{-iy}{x}$$

$$\to \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\pm iy}{x}$$

$$\to y = c|x|^{\pm i}$$

$$\to y = c_1|x|^{i}, \ y = c_2|x|^{-i}$$

Choose

$$\xi = c_1 = \frac{y}{|x|^{i}}$$

$$\eta = c_2 = \frac{y}{|x|^{-i}}$$

While remembering that $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable:

[image]